# Fonts not displayed on HTML email and underline comes for hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-email

I have an HTML email code as given in the below link:

https://privatebin.net/?1ca92ace7be6c777#LLNgtdGPXCC4Si0Ui7jsEt7P/g+PsZ1gRq08qBTOljo=

The issue is the fonts linked by **link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"** is not displayed correctly even though I have added inline styles to all tags.
Also an underline is displayed for the renew button. I tried by adding **text-decoration:none** style with !important. but was of no use.
Any opinions?

Comment: Most if the email clients doesn't support web fonts *yet*.

Answer (score 3):

you asked a few questions here so I'll do my best to answer them separately.

---

**Web fonts**, as mentioned by others, are [not supported in all email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/webfonts/). It's currently not possible to display web fonts in Outlook, Gmail app, or any webmail client. Be aware that fallback system fonts will display in some email clients no matter how the email is coded.

---

**For clients that *do* support web fonts**, something like this inside your `<head>` will get you the best possible coverage:

```
<!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->
<!--[if mso]>
    <style>
        * {
            font-family: sans-serif !important;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->

<!-- All other clients get the webfont reference; some will render the font and others will silently fail to the fallbacks. -->
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

More on web font support in email on [Style Campaign](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/) and [Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/typography-tips-for-email-designers).

---

Regarding **the underline in the button**, sometimes email clients place the default (and sometimes blue) underline in links within buttons. This can be reset by targeting a `<span>` inside the `<a href="">` button:

**CSS**

```
<head>
    <style>
        .button-link {
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

**HTML**

```
<table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #222222; text-align: center;">
            <a href="http://www.google.com" style="background: #222222; border: 15px solid #222222; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 110%; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;">
                <span style="color:#ffffff;" class="button-link">Button Text</span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nicely answered, +1 from myside

Comment: The issue is I am using it as a variable and sending the message through script. https://privatebin.net/?d3a0ad07349c8a20#BNTpKx0+WSNwz1vGQmhuJ4RCSfh+1C6iFK8Ah9Dnh/4= The thing is I am using the font name in double quotes in the script where the custom font is not loaded. But while designing I used single quotes which enabled the custom fonts.

Comment: Yea, you'll have issues with `<span style="font-family: "Source Sans Pro"...">`. Best to go with `<span style="font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'...">` , `<span style='font-family: "Source Sans Pro"...'>`or even `<span style="font-family: Source Sans Pro...">` might work.

Comment: When I am changing to <span style="font-family: 'Source Sans Pro'..."> it shows HTTP error. As the message itself is in single quotes

Comment: Then I would try it with no quotes: `<span style="font-family: Source Sans Pro...">`. It might not work, but you can't reuse the same double-quotes used to open the `style=""` attribute and if you can use single-quotes, not sure what other option you have.

Comment: With no quotes it is not working ; any other options to achieve it?

Comment: @RosyWilliams What email clients are you using to test the email?

Comment: You might try saving and hosting your own version of https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700. Then you can change `font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';` to `font-family: SourceSansPro;` and reference the font without quotes like `font-family: SourceSansPro;`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I didn't get you what exactly you're trying I think you want this applying `text-decoration: none;` to an anchor. try like this

```
a:hover { text-decoration:none; }
```

And if you want font to the body then apply this

```
body{ font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;}
```

Comment: <a href="#" target="_blank" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 55px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Verdana, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; line-height: 55px; text-decoration: none; white-space: nowrap; font-weight: 600;">

Comment: It is not on hover. The links are already displayed with an underline.

Comment: yeah because of default `a anchor` hover property.

Comment: I will try that, why the fonts are not displayed?

Comment: did you add this `font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;`

Comment: in the <head> part?

Comment: where exactly you want to add fonts.if you want for the complete body then apply to the body..

Comment: I want all the text in the email to have custom font.

Comment: apply to the body `font-family` i edited my answer check once.

Comment: The thing is I am adding the template as a variable. https://privatebin.net/?63caef972c96849b#QyXFi3NcppTmpkf3lKMlzPPIo5996rXQ4I8iBwGBfrc= when I add the font name in single quotes error appear. Is it because the fonts are not rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Web fonts do not work in all email clients. Some of the clients where they do not work include Gmail, Yahoo, some fonts do not work in Outlook and in email clients for Android devices.

You need to choose a backup font which will be used when Open Sans is not supported. I suggest Trebuchet or Arial or what meets your clients expectations for a fallback font. Something like this:

```
font-family: "Open Sans, Trebuchet, sans-serif;";
```

These links will give you a better understanding of web fonts and how to use them in email.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/font-face/
- https://www.cssfontstack.com
- https://www.cssfontstack.com/Open-Sans
- https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts

**Your Button Issue**

Your button only shows an underline in Windows Mail. However, the button shows up as Times New Roman in Outlook because you're using single quotes `''` in the font-family description. It sees that as an error and defaults to Times. You should address this.

You are having display problems with iPhone 5 and Android you should address before you send out the email.

Good luck.